# getting xmlvaluedisconnectedexception error when saving xlsx file java poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String excelFilePath = "sample.xlsx";
            FileInputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            Workbook workbook = null;
            try {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);

                Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();
                Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Row nextRow = iterator.next();

                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
                    Iterator<Cell> scellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

                    cellIterator.next();
                    scellIterator.next();
                    scellIterator.next();
                    Cell topicsCell = cellIterator.next();
                    Cell topicSentimentCell = scellIterator.next();

                    String cellContents = topicsCell.getStringCellValue();
                    String scellContents = topicSentimentCell.getStringCellValue();

                    String[] topics = cellContents.split(";");
                    String[] topicSentiment = scellContents.split(";");


                    for (int in = 0; in < topics.length; in++) {
                        Cell cell = row.getCell(in);
                        cell.setCellValue(textArea.getText());
                    }


                }

                try {
                    workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("sample.xlsx"));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

The Error

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_orphaned(XmlObjectBase.java:1258)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.newCursor(XmlObjectBase.java:286)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl.arraySetterHelper(XmlComplexContentImpl.java:1124)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontsImpl.setFontArray(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.writeTo(StylesTable.java:319)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.commit(StylesTable.java:377)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.onSave(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:177)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.onSave(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:181)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:214)
    at SR$4.actionPerformed(SR.java:298)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: What version of Apache POI is this with? And if it isn't the most recent, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: im using version 3.13

Comment: What happens if you write out to a different file to the one you're reading from?

Comment: same thing happens then also the saved file is 0kb

Comment: Does this happen with all files, or just some? What happens if you run the code as a standalone program, without any Swing or AWT stuff getting in the way?

Comment: it happens to all and same things happens without any swing

Comment: If you can put together some standalone sample-code that causes the problem it would be good if you can report a bug-report at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=POI

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but it can help someone.

The XmlValueDisconnectedException occurs when you try writing into a same file twice. This happened to me when I tried to convert Word into a Pdf.
Here's what helped me:

1. First I had to update versions of all Opensagres and Apache Poi dependencies.
2. Then I reloaded a workbook from document. Here is my code:

   ```
       FileInputStream is = FileUtils.openInputStream( templateFiles.get( 
       ConstantManager.FILE_NAME ) );
       XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument( is );
       tmpDoc = File.createTempFile( "tmp", "docx" );
       //replace body elements here...

       //write this into docx
       tmpDocx = File.createTempFile( "tmpDocx", "docx" );
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( tmpDocx );
       document.write( out );
       out.close();
       PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
       //KEY PART!!!           
       //it is not allowed to write into a document two times - 
       //org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException
       //that's why I have to reload a workbook from the file
       document = new XWPFDocument( new FileInputStream( tmpDocx ) );

       //and then convert to pdf
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( tmpDoc );
       PdfConverter.getInstance().convert( document, fos, options );
       fos.close();
       is.close();
       document.close();
   ```